# How to get member variables in collision detection functions?

Tags: javascript, chipmunk, cocos2d-js

I am working on a side scrolling game and using cocos2djs framework for that.
Currently I am trying to build collision detection functions, but I hit a bump.

I want to update my HUD with some information regarding player's health, when a collision occurs, however, I am not able to access member variables from inside these functions for some reason.

This is my collision handler (I use chipmunk physics)

```js
this.space.addCollisionHandler(pape,
                               obstacle,
                               this.collisionObstacleBegin,
                               null,
                               null,
                               null);
```

I handle the collision detection here `addCollisionHandler`:

```js
addCollisionHandler: function() {
    cc.log(this.healthStatus);
}
```

But the console shows `this.healthStatus` as undefined, even though it is defined and has been used for setting up the HUD earlier in the init function.
Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake, I forgot to bind the `collisionObstacleBegin`...

Comment: It's usual to declare `var self = this;` and use `self` in those event handlers, or bind as you did.